# Register permanent JDBC dialect sparkR

Tags: apache-spark, apache-drill

Is it possible to register a JDBC dialect permanently instead of writing it in a program? I'm wanting to register a JDBC dialect for the apache drill driver that uses tick marks (`) instead of quotes. I saw that this can be done in code from this post: [Integrating Spark SQL and Apache Drill through JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476076/integrating-spark-sql-and-apache-drill-through-jdbc)

But I am wanting to register a dialect permanently so I can implement sparkR from RStudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by building spark and adding ApacheDrillJDBCDialect